# Does anyone know who is the author of this lecture notes? (Lie Groups and Lie Algebras)

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, lie-algebras, lecture-notes

This is a simple question. I'm reading the following lecture notes (see the link below) and I'm trying to find who is the author since the notes are very well written. Does anyone know?

https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/563568428775317/notes.pdf

Comment: Someone from [the staff list](https://math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/officers) in Lisboa? This person wrote: "These are lecture notes for a graduate course on Lie Groups and Lie Algebras taught at IST Lisbon in the Fall semester of 2017/2018 and again in 2018/2019." So you can look up who taught this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Your tip helped a lot, thanks. https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~ggranja/lecturenotes.html (Gustavo Granja)